# I can't assignment a value to the cell python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(len(list_sort)):
    list_sort[i] = list_sort[i].reset_index()
    classification = 1
    list_sort[i].set_value(0, list_column[k], classification)
    for j in range(len(df))[1::]:
        if(list_sort[i].ix[j][1] == list_sort[i].ix[j-1][1]):
            list_sort[i].ix[j][2] = classification
        else:
            classification += 1
            list_sort[i].ix[j][2] = classification
    k += 2
    list_sort[i] = list_sort[i].set_index('index')
```

I have a list_sort that contain several DataFrame. Each one has a column that I need to compare the current line with the previous line.

This is part of the result when I compare a column where all values are type `int`:

```
     ACESSO_PORTAL  CLASSIFICACAO_ACESSO_PORTAL
index       
19     973693                 1
8      954719                 2
27     918459                 3
1      908029                 4
4      865346                 5
31     754591                 6
35     743908                 7
23     733344                 8
14     702816                 9
```

This is part of the result when I compare a column where all values are type `float`:

```
    TOTAL_PRODUTOS  CLASSIFICACAO_TOTAL_PRODUTOS
index       
19    118798.57                1
1     92415.46                 0
2     82987.19                 0
31    82228.57                 0
23    80109.00                 0
0     72606.59                 0
34    69385.11                 0
17    63794.19                 0
33    61328.62                 0
```

Each DataFrame has the index and two columns.

As you can see, it doesn't work with float.

I have not idea why happened this. I try use `set_value`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set a value on a copy:

> C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

On these lines:

```
        #This one...
        list_sort[i].ix[j][2] = classification
    else:
        classification += 1
        # And this one
        list_sort[i].ix[j][2] = classification
```

I don't think it's working with integers either.  I can't know for sure, because you did not provide sample data.

Try using `iloc` instead:

```
        list_sort[i].iloc[j, 2] = classification
        #       Here ^
    else:
        classification += 1
        list_sort[i].iloc[j, 2] = classification
        #   And here ^
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.